# Make 75% width for text and 100% for images in Wordpress post?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, width, wordpress-theming

I tried to make 75% width of paragraph in post, and also 100% responsive width of images. However, `<img>` is always in `<p>` as default.

```
<p>Some texts</p>
<p>Some texts</p>
<p><a><img src="..."></a></p>
<p>Some texts</p>
<p>Some texts</p>
```

Currently, I can only make `.entry-content p {max-width: 75%;}` and make a `<div>` outside the `<img>`. So that the system won't create a `<p>` to hold `<img>`. But it's not the best practice.

Any idea to this problem?

[image: This is my ideal layout]
This is the layout I expected.

Comment: If  `<p>` with `<img>` is always on third place u can do `p:nth-child(3){width:100%;}`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd thought. Since there's no parent selector, I can't make style on the `<p>` which containing `<img>`. I now can only look forward to pure JavaScript answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely do this with pure CSS - no need of JS for that - it's just maths. Considering your paragraphs are 75% of the container width, your image need to be 100% of paragraph width + the 25% missing of the container width. So with this formula you get the right percentage your image should have as width:

```
width = ((25/75) + 1) * 100 = 133.3333
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbhu8rnj/) illustrating this.